# Getopts more options trigger one event

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

im currently updating my first script i wrote to print room schedules
I want to use getopts to parse my options now my question:

My Options are to print the schdule for all rooms are:

- -w for the next day
- -e to print the schedule for monday on friday
- -c current day
- -O with an given offset

So far so good.

No i want to print only one room with following options:

- -rw
- -re
- -rc
- -rO

How can i manage that with getopts? Something like that?

```
while getopts :a:b:c:d:hP: ARG; do
  case $ARG in
    ab)  #set option "a"
      echo "-a used: $OPTARG"
      echo "OPT_A = $OPT_A"
      ;;
    cd)  #set option "b"
      echo "-b used: $OPTARG"
      echo "OPT_B = $OPT_B"
      ;;
```

Is that possible? I hope you understand what i mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define a variable `ONE_ROOM` which is set to true if the option `r` is given. You don't need to manually distinguish between all possible combinations of your arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

ONE_ROOM="0"

while getopts rwecO: ARG; do
  case $ARG in
    r) ONE_ROOM="1";;
    w) ;;
    e) ;;
    c) ;;
    O) ;;
  esac
done

if [ "$ONE_ROOM" -eq "1" ] ; then
  # print only one room
else
  # print all rooms
fi
```

Comment: I will check that. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I haven't marked it because i was to busy with stuff that i couldn't even try it. Easy Fix wonder why i wasn't able to think of it by myself. Works perfectly